# Mod_Rewrite how to ignore slashes that don't belong in url string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to setup canonical links in our forum and I need to come up with a rewrite rule that will ignores slashes that don't belong in the URL.

The proper URL would look like:

> http://www.truckingtruth.com/truckers-forum/Topic-20315/Page-1/speak-to-recruiter

For this I'm using the following mod_rewrite rule to pass the 'topic', 'page', and 'subjectString' variables:

> ^Topic-(.*)/Page-(.*)/(.*)$ index.html?topic=$1&page=$2&subjectString=$3

But sometimes improper links to our site or improper links in a comment will add slashes to the URL that don't belong there and it throws off the rule. Example:

> http://www.truckingtruth.com/truckers-forum/Topic-1652/Page-1/www.truckingtruth.com/free_truck_driving_schools/swift/how-to-use-the-qualcomm

When that happens the variables being passed are:

> topic = "1652"
>
> page = "1/www.truckingtruth.com/free_truck_driving_schools/swift"
>
> subjectString = "how-to-use-the-qualcomm"

What I want it to do is pass:

> topic = "1652"
>
> page = "1"
>
> subjectString = "www.truckingtruth.com/free_truck_driving_schools/swift/how-to-use-the-qualcomm"

How can I create a rewrite rule that will pass everything after "Page-1" as the subjectString even if there are slashes in it?

Comment: Are `topic` and `page` always integers?

Comment: No. Page can be "Newest" or "Last" or an integer. Topic is always an integer.

Comment: `^Topic-(\d*)/Page-([^/]*)/(.*)$` should do, https://regex101.com/r/7TNSa1/1

Comment: That did it! Awesome! Thanks a ton. I had no idea that regex101.com even existed so that's a double bonus. Thanks. Can you put your answer as a regular reply so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `topic` is always integer, for your first capturing group you can use `\d` which matches any decimal digit (equivalent to [0-9]).

For `page`, just make sure not to include any slashes, `[^/]` will take care of that.
The rest should then all go to third capturing group, so the resulting regex will be:

```
^Topic-(\d*)/Page-([^/]*)/(.*)$
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!